# Global geospatial data on roads that includes year built?

Tags: geospatial, infrastructure

Can anyone recommend geospatial data sources for roads that have wide geographic coverage *and* provide road construction year? I have come across the [Global Roads Inventory Project (GRIP)](https://www.globio.info/download-grip-dataset), which usefully harmonizes numerous global or lower-level datasets into a massive one. But the issue for my case is that each road is coded for the year in which one of the original datasets observed it, rather than that road's actual year of construction. I am interested in mapping out road construction over time for most if not all world regions. Using one dataset or compiling multiple sources would be fine.